# multi column ajustar conteudo

Tags: php, css, css3

Estou pegando do bando resultados de uma pesquisa e exibindo em uma div usando column count

```
width:800px; -webkit-column-count: 3;-moz-column-count: 3;column-count: 3;
```

porem preciso que a coluna seja fechada no final da frase ou em algum tipo de coringa.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o anuncio é exibido sem que esteja inteiro, precisava que fosse exibido o bloco de anuncio depois sim o proximo bloco ir para a outra coluna

Comment: Você pode elaborar um pouco mais sua pergunta? Está um pouco difícil entender o que você está querendo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você precisa adicionar a propriedade **[break-inside](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/#break-inside)** para determinar a quebra de colunas:

```
-webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
-moz-column-break-inside:avoid;
-moz-page-break-inside:avoid;
page-break-inside: avoid;
break-inside: avoid;
```

No caso `avoid` evite a quebra de coluna

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NX27g/3/)**

Comment: muito obrigado era isso mesmo, não conhecia sobre essa parte do break ajudou muito :)